# Web Audio API select channel to play

Tags: audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am new to Web Audio API, i am working on a web app where users will select a video and that video will contain 2 channels:

Ch 1: Original Version (Full Mix)
Ch 2: M&E version (Music & Effect No Dialogue)

I need to give user the option to select the channel he wants to play for video.

I have seen that it can be possible using Web Audio API, but I am not able to write proper code for this.

Any help will be really apriciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you streaming the video?  HLS.js, for example, has built-in methods for track selection.  No need for the Web Audio API here.

Comment: @Brad i am using html5 player and VideoFrame.Js and i also i have a custom script for recording, now i can't use any other library for playing videos, i just need to add some extra scripts for switching the channel.